# Get column index label based on values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have the following:

```
          C1       C2     C3
0         0        0      1 
1         0        0      1
2         0        0      1
```

**And i would like to get the corresponding column index value that has 1's, so the result
should be "C3".**

I know how to do this by transposing the dataframe and then getting the index values, but this is not ideal for data in the dataframes i have, and i wonder there might be a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will save the result in a `list` because otherwise there could be more than one column with values ​​equal to 1. You can use [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

**if all column values ​​must be 1 then you can use**:

```
df.loc[:,df.eq(1).all()].columns.tolist()
```

**Output:**

```
['C3']
```

---

if this isn't necessary then use:

```
df.loc[:,df.eq(1).any()].columns.tolist()
```

or as suggested **@piRSquared**, you can select directly from `df.columns`:

```
[*df.columns[df.eq(1).all()]]
```

Comment: **Golfed:** `[*df.columns[df.eq(1).all()]]` (-:

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared !